# How to tag a non critical test case in TestNG and Maven failsafe plugin

Tags: testng, maven-failsafe-plugin

Test Execution should be successful even the non-critical test case failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Ignore annotation when you know that test is broken and you can't fix it immediately. Such test wouldn't be executed and build will pass.

Another option is just comment out @Test annotation:

```
// @Test
public void testMethod(){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks ikrnac. Reason behind my question was "if am developing a test case which is very long and i know that it will break the run but still want to test till developed in the build cycle. If there is any way to tag that can this test case as a development test case which can run in the build cycle and also my build should be green.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. I can't think of use case when I create test that is failing and I want to run it with build.

Comment: This is a use case when we are following Automated Test Driven Development(ATDD)

Comment: It is fundamental principle of Continuous development and TDD (you call it ATDD) process: Failing test must fail the build. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495560/should-failing-tests-make-the-continuous-build-fail#495580

Comment: BTW, when I google for ATDD, it points me to Acceptance Test Driven Development. Which is obviously different term.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the test to belong to a group, say UNDERDEV.  Implement the listener [IInvokedMethodListener](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener.html).  In the afterInvocation method, write something to the effect,

```
if((testResult.getStatus() == TestResult.FAILURE)  && Arrays.asList(method.getTestMethod().getGroups()).contains("UNDERDEV"))
            //Set status to passed
```